# I wrote a java project Java SE which I want to start when windows starts

Tags: windows

I wrote a Java project using Java SE.

I want the program to start when Windows starts, how can I do that ?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/run-a-program-automatically-when-windows-starts

Comment: Maybe move this question to [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the executable file of your java program into the Windows Startup 
From a run box type `msconfig` and select the Startup Tab. Then your program will run automatically when Windows starts. You can also use tools like `Autoruns` to manage programs executed at start up.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your program is, you've got a couple of options.

The simplest is to create a shortcut in the Startup folder of the start menu that points at javaw.exe passing the parameters needed to run your program.  This normally involves packing your program in an [excutable jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) and something like `javax.exe -jar [your jar]` as the shortcut target.  This method will only start the program when a user logs in.

If you need something a little more advanced, for example if your program is going to run on a Windows server, then you're going to need to register a Windows service on that server.  To the best of my knowledge you cannot do this with just Java and therefore need a 3rd party application that can act as the service and start your Java program accordingly.  For this look at [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).